# Unity3d Ugly Road Seams

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Im trying to make a road in unity3d with blender, but when i try to make the piecing together i get ugly seems where the roads come together..
as of now my road is just a plane, should i make this to be a full box instead?

This is the seam:

[image]

And this is my model:

[image]

EDIT:
I managed to fix my problem by turning all my planes into boxes..
like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your images are so small it is hard to understand issue from them, anyway as i understand your moddel's edge's are seem weird right?

Did you try to look them after the compile, editor scene show much more ugly because it needs to be fast but after compiling and playing it look much more nice.

And also you can make some post processing to get better quality.

I think i could not manage to tell in the best way but i hope it can help you...

Comment: thank you.. yes the problem is the seams of the road are very noticable..
i will try to look at it compiles see if anything changes.. thank you..

Comment: If it does not solve your problem please let me know i and will find another way to solve the issue :)

Comment: Thank you.. i fixed it by turning all my planes into boxes..
show fixed image on thread edit.